# Laravel code in HasAttributes-Trait nonsense?

Tags: php, laravel

I took a look into the source code of laravel and found the following code:

```
    $attributes = $this->addDateAttributesToArray(
        $attributes = $this->getArrayableAttributes()
    );
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2244814657a93959448561e5acb70cc703cdfe35/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L90-L92)

as you can see, there are assignments to the `$attributes` variable. One of them is in the parameter list. Albeit this is valid syntax, its immediately overwritten by the "outer" assignment.

Why would someone write code like this? Is there a special behavior I am not aware of?

Comment: Might want to create an issue on the repository if you think this is an error. They will probably also know better why this is so. And if you do, please link the issue here, I am intrigued as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you can clearly see in the comments.

> If an attribute is a date, we will cast it to a string after converting it
>      to a DateTime / Carbon instance. This is so we will get some consistent
>      formatting while accessing attributes vs. arraying / JSONing a model.

Secondly there is nothing fancy in this. it is just technique to make program readable though.

Here is an example.

```
return new HttPStatus(301);
```

- can you tell me about the about what the above-given code is doing?.

  Maybe you will google and about 301 HTTP status code which tells us that the 301 Moved Permanently is used for permanent URL redirection.

Let's have a look at another example.

```
json_decode($string, true);
```

- Can you tell me about why we are passing `true`.?
- whats it's purpose.?

if you are not experienced with `json_decode($string, true);` you will google again why we have to pass a `true` in `json_decode()`.

lets have another example.

```
json_decode($string, $returnArray = true);
```

Now from the above code you can we can clearly understand if we pass `true` it will return an array. `$returnArray = true` is just a throwaway variable which increases the readability of your code.

Same is the case with this

```
// If an attribute is a date, we will cast it to a string after converting it
// to a DateTime / Carbon instance. This is so we will get some consistent
// formatting while accessing attributes vs. arraying / JSONing a model.
$attributes = $this->addDateAttributesToArray(
    $attributes = $this->getArrayableAttributes()
);
```

`$attributes = $this->getArrayableAttributes()` it is just a throwaway variable which tells us that we are passing attributes, which increases readability of code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats strange because I cannot find it anywhere else in the code and there would be a lot more oppurtunities